# GWT - RichTextArea - formatter fires

Tags: gwt

I have my RichTextArea formatter settings as

```
void initUI(){//invoke in default constructor...
            getRichTextArea().getFormatter().setFontName("Verdana");
            getRichTextArea().getFormatter().setFontSize(FontSize.X_SMALL);
            getRichTextArea().getFormatter().setForeColor("gray");
}
```

Next I am wondering how to clear RichTextArea correctly and keep its formatter because I tried code like

```
getRichTextArea().setText(null);//invoke on some button click...
```

... and it really removed all inner text but when I try to re-input text the whole formatting setting are fired or something because the re-inputted text has default font and color etc not the formatted ones :(

... by the way method like `getRichTextArea().getFormatter().undo();` removes formatter settings as well :(

So my question is... how to clear rich text area and keep its formatting?

Thanks

P.S. GWT 2.3

Comment: Edited my answer to add how to change body styles using gwt + jsni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need cursor control in the RichTextArea to position the cursor, select a range, and remove text.

This ability is not present in the gwt RichTextArea, but there is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1127) which has a long discussion, some patches and a [library (gwt-selection)](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-selection/) implementing it. The issue has been closed recently because gwt maintainers are getting rid of all issues which have not had recent activity, but maybe you could reopen it or ping the owner to do that. Using this library you could get a portion of the document and remove it without deleting format tags.

Anyway if you need to remove the complete text and set some default css to all the content, what you can do is to style the body of the RichTextArea iframe.

With [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) getting the content body to style it is easy:

```java
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;

[...]

// First attach the widget to the DOM
RootPanel.get().add(richTextArea);

// We only can manipulate the body, once the iframe document has been created, 
// and this happens after it has been attached. 
// Because richtTextArea uses a timeout to initialize we need a delay.
$(richTextArea)
  .delay(1, 
    lazy()
      .contents().find("body")
        .css("font-name", "verdana")
        .css("font-size", "x-small")
        .css("color", "gray")
    .done());
```

If you want to do the same without importing gwtquery you need some jsni to get the body element after the RichTextArea has been attached and initialized:

```java
// First attach the widget to the DOM
RootPanel.get().add(richTextArea);

// We only can manipulate the body, once the iframe document has been created, 
// and this happens after it has been attached.
// Using a timer because richtTextArea uses a timeout to initialize
new Timer() {

  // There is no method to get the body, so we use JSNI
  private native Element getBodyElement(Element iframe) /*-{
    return iframe.contentWindow.document.body;
  }-*/;

  public void run() {
    Element e = getBodyElement(richTextArea.getElement());
    e.getStyle().setProperty("fontName", "Verdana");
    e.getStyle().setProperty("fontSize", "x-small");
    e.getStyle().setProperty("color", "gray");
  }
}.schedule(1);
```

Comment: It is quite interesting; thank you. So you offer to set styles right into rich text area itself as an element... But how in this case do you suggest to clear it on lets say a button click? I mean reset all its inner text? Is it something in JSNI area, too, or it is OK with setText("")? What do you think?

Comment: What I say, is that normally when adding a RichTextArea to the UI, developer wants to set some default styles. You can either modify the document adding tags wrapping the cursor or modify the entire body. Your solution is the first case, so when you use setText(""), you remove those tags. My solution is to style the body, so setText("") will preserve styles.

Comment: OK I got it. But I've being thinking... is there a way to extract rich text area body on pure gwt for example? What you think?

Comment: No, there is no method to get the body element in gwt-core.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what the "formatting" is. Rich text means it contains multiple secions, and each section has it's own style and attribute. So there is no "default" one. You have to define one.

Actually under the rich text area it's just a div with contenteditable=true. If you put it into a styled container (another div), it will inherit the style in it. That way you can define some default style.

Another way is make sure what attributes you want and specify it with Formatter directly.

I don't see there is any other way to achieve this. Formatter is just a wrapper to execCommand and the behavior is browser dependent. Let's do some analysis.

This is your rich text area

```
<div contenteditable=true>hello, world!</div>
```

If you select all text and invoke `Formatter.toggleBold()`, you will get:

```
<div contenteditable=true><b>hello, world!</b></div>
```

If you do `setText('')` which really do `div.innerText=''`, you will get

```
<div contenteditable=true></div>
```

Your format lost.

You can only do workaround to maintain the style, either by putting it into a container and set style on the container, or remember what formatting used and reapply it after setText().

Comment: No, I have my rich text area formatted. The thing is how to clear it from text not to remove formatting? As I was saying, if to use code like setText("") etc it removes text and it removes formatter settings as well :( So that's the question really is... I edited my question (added code snippet) watch it please

Comment: I mean the rich text area by composite constructor load has formatter which has settings (as my code snippets says); So I try , for example, to reset all its text by invoking code like a getRichTextArea().setText(""); the text disappears but, as I can see it, all the text area styles (formatting) get lost as well for my pity :S So how can I fix it? And how you think is there a way to fix it with pure GWT?

Comment: I think I stated it clear: "You can only do workaround to maintain the style, either by putting it into a container and set style on the container, or remember what formatting used and reapply it after setText()."